# radiance theme in gnome flashback in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: radiance

What happened with the color of the icons in the radiance theme in gnome flashback in Ubuntu 18.04?
They are almost invisible now:
[Ubuntu 18.04 radiance theme tray icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5E9c.png)

Looking at the same in Ubuntu 14.04:
[Ubuntu 14.04 radiance theme tray icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL1gk.png)

Is there anything that could be done to make them look similar like in 14.04?

Regards
JR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Gnome Tweaks (`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks`). It allows you to change the icon theme.

You may need to change to

- a "Light" variant of the Humanity icon theme:

  > [image: Humanity]
- or "Ubuntu-mono-light" with darker icons:

  > [image: Ubuntu-mono-light]